# Kinda new to Python Programming and was attempting a question. I just don't know why this error keeps popping up. Really doesn't make sense to me

Tags: python, list, loops

This was the question: Create a function named `add_greetings()` which takes a list of strings named names as a parameter.

In the function, create an empty list that will contain each greeting. Add the string `"Hello, "` in front of each name in names and append the greeting to the list.

Return the new list containing the greetings.

Quite a basic question but I accidentally initialized the new list outside the function like this:

```
new_lst = []

def add_greetings(names):
    for name in names:
        name = "Hello, " + name
        new_lst.append(name)
    return new_lst

print(add_greetings(["Owen", "Max", "Sophie"]))
```

This was a question on Codecademy and it gave me this error:

`add_greetings(["Owen", "Max", "Sophie"])` should have returned `['Hello, Owen', 'Hello, Max', 'Hello, Sophie']`, and it returned `[‘Hello, Owen’, ‘Hello, Max’, ‘Hello, Sophie’, ‘Hello, Owen’, ‘Hello, Owen’, ‘Hello, Max’, ‘Hello, Sophie’]`

Why is this the case? Tried it on the Python IDE, and it gave me the expected correct answer.

Comment: `new_lst` is global scope so each time `add_greetings` is called you're appending additional items to the list. Based on your output you've called it more than once during your session. Just declare `new_lst` inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

You should try instantiating the new_list inside the function:

```py
def add_greetings(names):
    new_lst = []
    for name in names:
        name = "Hello, " + name
        new_lst.append(name)
    return new_lst

print(add_greetings(["Owen", "Max", "Sophie"]))
```

What ends up happening when Codeacademy tests it is they will run more than one test case. When you run your method more than once, it will continue appending to the same list over and over again, and will therefore return the wrong result. This can be mitigated by putting the list initialization *inside* the function itself, so you start fresh each time.